# Jetbrains Academy Java: Program ran out of input. You tried to read more, than expected

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

The Jetbrains Academy Java "Project: Cinema Room Manager" at stage 4/5 throws an unclear error `Program ran out of input. You tried to read more, than expected....`. The Java stack trace is:

```
at org.hyperskill.hstest.stage.StageTest.start(StageTest.java:131)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

## Source code

SeatPlanning.java

```
package cinema;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeatPlanning {
    private int rows;
    private int seatsPerRow;

    private String[][] seats;

    private final Scanner s;

    public SeatPlanning() {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public int getTicketPrice(int row) {
        int totalSeats = rows * seatsPerRow;
        if (totalSeats <= 60) {
            return 10;
        } else {
            int frontRows = (int) Math.floor((double) rows / 2);
            return (row <= frontRows) ? 10 : 8;
        }
    }

    public void printTicketPrice(int row) {
        System.out.printf("Ticket price: $%d\n", getTicketPrice(row));
    }

    private void printInputRequest(String str) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", str);
        System.out.print("> ");
    }

    public void launch() {
        printInputRequest("Enter the number of rows:");
        rows = s.nextInt();
        printInputRequest("Enter the number of seats in each row:");
        seatsPerRow = s.nextInt();
        initSeats();
        printMenu();
    }

    private void initSeats() {
        this.seats = new String[rows][seatsPerRow];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < seatsPerRow; column++) {
                this.seats[row][column] = " S";
            }
        }
    }

    public void printSeats() {
        System.out.print("\nCinema:\n ");
        for (int column = 0; column < seatsPerRow; column++) {
            System.out.printf(" %d", column + 1);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", row + 1);
            for (int column = 0; column < seatsPerRow; column++) {
                System.out.print(seats[row][column]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    private void buySeat(int row, int column) {
        this.seats[row - 1][column - 1] = " B";
        printTicketPrice(row);
    }


    public void startBuySeatDialog() {
        printInputRequest("Enter a row number:");
        int row = s.nextInt();
        printInputRequest("Enter a seat number in that row:");
        int column = s.nextInt();
        buySeat(row, column);
    }


    public void printMenu() {
        printInputRequest("\n1. Show the seats\n" +
                "2. Buy a ticket\n" +
                "0. Exit");
        evaluateMenuOption(s.nextInt());

    }

    private void evaluateMenuOption(int option) {
        switch (option) {
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
            case 1:
                this.printSeats();
                this.printMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.startBuySeatDialog();
                this.printMenu();

        }
    }
}
```

Cinema.java

```
package cinema;

public class Cinema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SeatPlanning seatPlanning = new SeatPlanning();
        seatPlanning.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have used `System.exit(0)` to quit the application which is the culprit of the problem.
Instead, use `return` to quit the application.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? if not, please avoid posting comments as answers.

Comment: Yes, I used the "answer you own question" functionality. I found the answer way burrowed in hyperskill comments, hence I wanted to share the answer more publicly for everyone who's googling in the future

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have put your code inside a while() to get multiple inputs from the user but in the current stage, it only needs one input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for stage 4/5:

```
package cinema;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cinema {

static boolean withPrice = false;

static class Seat {
    boolean occupied = false;
    int price = 0;

    public Seat(boolean occupied, int price) {
        this.occupied = occupied;
        this.price = price;
    }

    String print(boolean withPrice) {
        if(withPrice) {
            return String.format("%c (%02d)", (occupied == true) ? 'B' : 'S', price);
        } else
            return String.format("%c", (occupied == true) ? 'B' : 'S');
    }
}

static int noOfRows;
static int noOfSeats;
static Seat[][] seats;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: \n> ");
    noOfRows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of seats in each row: \n> ");
    noOfSeats = scanner.nextInt();

    int income = 0;
    if (noOfRows * noOfSeats <= 60) {
        income = noOfRows * noOfSeats * 10;
    } else {
        income = (noOfRows / 2) * noOfSeats * 10 +
                (noOfRows - (noOfRows / 2)) * noOfSeats * 8;
    }

    // System.out.println("Total income: \n$" + income);

    //
    // initialize seats
    //
    seats = new Seat[noOfRows][];
    for(int currRow = 0; currRow < noOfRows; currRow++) {
        seats[currRow] = new Seat[noOfSeats];
        for(int currSeat = 0; currSeat < noOfSeats; currSeat++) {
            int price = 0;
            if (noOfRows * noOfSeats > 60 && currRow >= noOfRows / 2) {
                price = 8;
            } else {
                price = 10;
            }

            seats[currRow][currSeat] = new Seat(false, price);
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
        System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
        System.out.print("0. Exit\n> ");
        int menu = scanner.nextInt();

        if(menu == 1) {

            printCinemaRoom(withPrice);

        } else if(menu == 2) {

            System.out.print("Enter a row number: \n> ");
            int reserveRow = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            System.out.print("Enter a seat number in that row: \n> ");
            int reserveSeat = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            seats[reserveRow][reserveSeat].occupied = true;

            System.out.println("Ticket price: $" + seats[reserveRow][reserveSeat].price);
        } else if (menu == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

}

private static void printCinemaRoom(boolean withPrice) {
    System.out.print("\nCinema:\n ");
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfSeats; i++) {
        System.out.printf(" %d", (i + 1) );
        if(withPrice)
            System.out.printf(" (%02d)", 0 );
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for(int currRow = 0; currRow < noOfRows; currRow++) {

        // print row number
        System.out.print((currRow + 1) + " ");

        // print seats
        for(int currSeat = 0; currSeat < noOfSeats; currSeat++) {
            System.out.print(seats[currRow][currSeat].print(withPrice) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```